# Reverse Slice of strings

Tags: go

I don't understand what is wrong with the below implementation, I had a look at `sort.StringSlice` and it looks the same.

```
type RevStr []string

func(s RevStr) Len() int { return len(s) }
func(s RevStr) Less(i, j int) bool { return s[i] < s[j] }
func(s RevStr) Swap(i, j int) { s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i] }

func Reverse(input string) string {
  rs := RevStr(strings.Split(input, " "))
  sort.Reverse(rs)
  return strings.Join(rs, " ")
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`sort.Reverse`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Reverse) doesn't sort the data, but rather returns a new `sort.Interface` that will sort the data in reverse order. So you don't really need your own type:

```
func Reverse(input string) string {
    s := strings.Split(input, " ")
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.StringSlice(s)))
    return strings.Join(s, " ")
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/w49FDCEHo3.

**EDIT:** If you just need to reverse a slice of strings, just do:

```
func reverse(ss []string) {
    last := len(ss) - 1
    for i := 0; i < len(ss)/2; i++ {
        ss[i], ss[last-i] = ss[last-i], ss[i]
    }
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/UptIRFV_SI

Comment: thx, for the answer, I know that I don't need a custom type and that I can use sort.StringSplice(s); the other thing is I don't want to sort, just to return the reverse.

Comment: @RockNinja See edit. As you already know, `sort.Reverse` doesn't do what you want, but it's still easy to do.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong with your `RevStr` type (though you could just use `sort.StringSlice`). You're not calling `sort.Sort` on the reversed implementation:

https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#example_Reverse

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    s := []int{5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4} // unsorted
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(s)))
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Comment: I wanted to reverse my string without sorting it, and I played a bit with sort.Reverse and I had the feeling that is reversing the input without being wrapped by sort.Sort, my bad :(

Comment: @RockNinja: if you don't want to sort it, don't use the "sort" package -- just reverse the slice yourself.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner solution (using a lambda):

Given:

```
myStrings := []string{"apple", "banana", "cherry"}
```

Sort (in reverse order) with:

```
sort.Slice(myStrings, func(i, j int) bool { return myStrings[i] > myStrings[j]})
```

Playground Example:
https://play.golang.org/p/WZabAZTizHG

Answer (score 1):

Although @Ainar-G has provided a way to reverse a slice of strings, I think it's nicer to use two variables in for loop to reverse. But it's only my personal opinion, a matter of style :)

```
func reverse(s []string) []string {
    for i, j := 0, len(s)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
    }
    return s
}
```

Playground link with example of usage: http://play.golang.org/p/v1Cy61NFv1

Answer (score 0):

More simple way, without using built-in sorting feature :

```
   func reverse(s []string) []string {
       for i := len(s) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
         result = append(result, s[i])
       }
    return s
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func reverseStr(data []string) []string {
m := len(data) - 1
var out = []string{}
for i := m; i >= 0; i-- {
    out = append(out, data[i])
  }
  return out
}
```

Comment: Please explain the advantages of this solution over the strikingly similar, older https://stackoverflow.com/a/67199574/7733418

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.